# Can I use custom XML parts in Word 2010 VBA?

Tags: xml, vba, vsto, ms-word

I need to save some custom infos into a word 2010 document, I can use hidden texts, bookmarks, custom doc properties, content controls, etc, but all of these methods cannot work with large data very well, and these methods are fragile and are't very flexible. So I want to use custom XML parts, which can hold large data, and are flexible. But I hope to use only VBA without VS2010/VSTO. I want to know whether I can use custom XML parts with only VBA, and how to do.

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can.

In the object browser, have a look at Office.CustomXMLParts (which has an Add method), and CustomXMLPart.

It all works pretty well.

Comment: Thanks you very much. I've see it.